# JAVA: How do I read this file? //SCHOOL PROJECT NO EXTRA LIBRARIES ALLOWED//

Tags: java

So I need to read in a text file with levels for sokoban

```
; 1

    #####
    #   #
    #$  #
  ###  $##
  #  $ $ #
### # ## #   ######
#   # ## #####  ..#
# $  $          ..#
##### ### #@##  ..#
    #     #########
    ####### 
; 2

############
#..  #     ###
#..  # $  $  #
#..  #$####  #
#..    @ ##  #
#..  # #  $ ##
###### ##$ $ #
  # $  $ $ $ #
  #    #     #
  ############ 
;
```

How do I write every level in a seperate array item so I can desplay them seperate later?
They need to go from ; to ; but the rows need to be intact

```
public class LevelReader {
private List<String> levels;
private final InputStream inputStream;


public LevelReader() {

    this.inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Levels.txt");
    this.readLevels();


}


private void readLevels() {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            levels = new ArrayList<>();
            if (line.startsWith(";")) {
                levels.addAll(lines);
                lines.clear();
                System.out.println(levels);
            }
            lines.add(line);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

```
At this moment it kinda works but i still get alotof errors
[; 48, ,   #########,   #*.*#*.*#,   #.*.*.*.#,   #*.*.*.*#,   #.*.*.*.#,   #*.*.*.*#,   ###   ###,     #   #, ###### ######, #           #, # $ $ $ $ $ #, ## $ $ $ $ ##,  #$ $ $ $ $#,  #   $@$   #,  #  #####  #,  ####   #### ]
[; 49, ,        ####,        #  ##,        #   ##,        # $$ ##,      ###$  $ ##,   ####    $   #, ###  # #####  #, #    # #....$ #, # #   $ ....# #, #  $ # #.*..# #, ###  #### ### #,   #### @$  ##$##,      ### $     #,        #  ##   #,        ######### ]
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Model.LevelReader.readLevels(LevelReader.java:33)
    at Model.LevelReader.<init>(LevelReader.java:19)
    at MainMenu.MainMenuPresenter$2.handle(MainMenuPresenter.java:51)
    at MainMenu.MainMenuPresenter$2.handle(MainMenuPresenter.java:44)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: This seems to be a homework for me. try to look up java tutorials instead of asking here.

Comment: What is `Levels`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading into a list of lines; Whenever you encounter a separator line, emit a new level ...

Sth. like this:

```
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        while (line != null) {
            String[] level = ;
            line = reader.readLine();
            if (line.startsWith(";")) {
               levels.add(new Level(lines));
               lines.clear();
            }
            else {
               lines.add(line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This helped me alot further tnx! 
(I Update the things i made and recieved as print

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use a bufferedReader you could do something like this

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/file.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
String line = reader.readLine();

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while((line != null){
    list.add(line);
    line = reader.readline
}
```

Comment: True but then he only reads it line per line, we need to load a whole level so multiple lines until we reach another ;
for example if we want to sout(list.get 3 we want to printout the whole level)

Comment: Did this work? Is this the type of thing you were looking for?
If so, please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use guava's Splitter, don't reinvent the wheel.

Read the file into a String, then split it. Your file shouldn't be too big, so it should be possible to read it into a String.

With Google Guava library you basically import a splitter, and define it this way:

```
List<String> levelsAsString = Splitter.on(',').split(fileAsString);
```

Then you have all levels as strings. then you can split it row by row:

```
Splitter lineSplitter = Splitter.on(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
List<String> linesForLevel1 = lineSplitter.split(levelsAsString.get(0));
```

[Guava documentation](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)

Comment: We are not allowed to use Google Guava :/

Comment: In your question you didn't say this is a school project. This is a valid answer for your current question.
Edit your question so it is clear that you can't use libraries, and explain the reason as well.

Comment: sorry first time :/